# how to refence bundles after migrating the code to html and javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

I have one index.cshtml file in which there is code lined as

```
(@Styles.RenderFormat(@"<link rel=""stylesheet"" href="" {0}"" 
         async/>","~/Content/csslogin")
```

which is referencing to a file written in ASP.NET having bundles containing CSS 
 files.

Now I am migrating that .cshtml and ASP.NET file to HTML and 
 JavaScript/angularjs file respectively. So what is the syntax to create a bundle in 
 JavaScript/angularjs and reference that JavaScript/angularjs bundle from HTML file?

Code in .cshtml file

```
@Styles.RenderFormat(@"<link rel=""stylesheet"" href="" {0}"" 
            async/>", "~/Content/csslogin")
```

Code in .cs file

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
                     {
                          bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/csslogin")
                                 .Include("~/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css")
                                  );
```

Comment: The bundle is usually created in C# and is referenced in cshtml. What do you mean by creating a bundle in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has this syntax if used in the cshtml file:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/csslogin")
```

For javascript files the syntax is:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/script/lib")
```

And in the bundles config:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/script/lib")
    .Include("~/scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js")
    .IncludeDirectory("~/content/rateit", "*.js")
);
```

Comment: Thankyou..This the syntax for referencing the bundle in Javascript file...Can you also tell me the syntax for creating bundles in Javascript.

Comment: For javascript files, the syntax is very similar, updated the answer.

Comment: But the ScriptBundle is a class offered by ASP.NET MVC Framework but I am not using ASP.NET framework..I need to implement it in such a way that it should be deployable in Tomcat server...so is there any way to create bundles without using ASP.NET MVC Framework..

Comment: Ah, sorry, this article contains some information about bundling: https://medium.com/@davembush/adding-css-and-javascript-to-an-angular-cli-project-2b843a8283f3